# Change priorities of ALL processes

Tags: linux, shell

I know that you can modify the nice value of a particular process as follows:

renice 19 -p 4567

However, now I would be interested to set the renice value of ALL active processes.
I am coming from the Win world so what I tried wa

renice 19 -p *

Of course it is not working... Anyone a quick solution how to do that in Linux?

Many thanks,
Martin

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: doing some timings and for that I would like to lower the priority of some of the the active processes

Comment: @Martin: Have you considered doing the opposite, ie. making your process' priority higher?

Comment: Yes I have, but still I wanna lower the process of all the others ;)

Comment: Theoretically, your process is already held above the others. In theory, the perfomance gain would be minimal. In theory.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you mean *all* processes? There are quite a few system processes that you can't renice except as root. `ps -u $(whoami) | awk '{print $1}'` will give you all of your pids. You can run them through a loop to renice them as you please.

```
for i in $(ps -u $(whoami) | awk '{print $1}')
do
  renice 19 $i
done
```

My shell is rusty so please double check.

Comment: In this case you can simply use `renice 19 -u $(whoami)` for the same effect.